# How do i download the latest version of Python onto my Linux system?

Tags: lubuntu, python

I can't figure out how or where to find the download for Python. If you don't know, Python is a coding language. I want to learn to code. If you recommend a different thing to learn code, please reply with a link and what it is below. I would like to use Python but I want to learn how to code soon.

Comment: Whatever you do, do not modify existing python in Ubuntu. System requires the links to current version to work correctly.  And your install should have both python2 and python3, but default link of python is currently to python2. Just use python3 if you want that.

Answer (score 1):

It it wasn't installed by default, use `sudo apt-get install python` or `sudo apt-get install python3` for debian based systems

Also [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/python) is a good place to start to learn python

Comment: I checked out Code Academy. I love it! Thanks!

Comment: @VoyagerLinuxGamer No problem. There are lots of other sites that have tutorials. and Lots of documents. A little searching will get you lots of places for information

Answer (score 1):

Python is available through your package manager via the official repositories.

Option one, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Option two, use the software center:

open the ubuntu software center and search for python.

For the pip package manager, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

or, for the python3 version:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

To learn python for free:

[www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/)

---

If you insist on a manual install (not really recommended), you can build the absolute latest from source using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.0/Python-3.5.0b2.tgz
tar zxvf Python-3.5*
cd Python-3.5*
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest learning ruby instead:

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/

Comment: the user asked for alternative language too but whatever...

Comment: I missed that, sorry.